# Java XML Freemarker two hashmap in one sequnece

Tags: java, c, xml, freemarker

I want to generate two C enums with comments. Corresponding data are stored in a XML file.

So, I read two tags, ID and Comment from the XML data using Java. ID and Comment are stored in two separate hashmaps. Both of the hashmaps are part of an arraylist of (the same) objects. I have also the setter and getter function.
I am able to generate separately the Comments and the IDs. However, I am not able to generate ID and Comment in the same sequence.

```
**File 0:**
Class example {
   private Map<String, String> idList    = new HashMap<String, String>();
   private Map<String, String> cmtList   = new HashMap<String, String>();

   public Map<String, String> getIdList() {    
      return this.idList;
   };
   public Map<String, String> getCmtList() {    
      return this.cmtList;
  };
}

File 1:
List<example> Freemarker_arr = new ArrayList< example >();

public List< example > getXmlModes() {
    return Freemarker_arr;
}


File 2: 
<#list model.getXmlModes() as i>
<#list i.getIdList()?keys as id>
typedef enum 
{
   ${"ABC_ID" + id},            // This one works fine. Ids are generated.
} value_st;
</#list>
</#list>

<#list model.getXmlModes() as i>
<#list i.getCmtList()?keys as cmt>
typedef enum 
{
    ${cmt},                 // This one works also fine. Comments are generated.
} value_st;
</#list>
</#list>
```

**Problem:**

```
I want to generate:
// Comment 1
// Enum 1

// Comment 2
// Enum 2
```

Code:

```
<#list model.getXmlModes() as i>
<#list i.getIdList()?keys as id>
<#list i.getCmtList()?keys as cmt>
// ${cmt}
typedef enum 
{
    ${"ABC_ID" + id},
} value_st;
</#list>
</#list>
</#list>
```

I read altogether 2 IDs and 2 Comments from the xml file. The below code will be generated four times...

Generated output:

```
// Comment 1
// Enum 1

// Comment 1
// Enum 2

// Comment 2 
// Enum 1

// Comment 2 
// Enum 2
```

**Question:**
What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You should `#list` only one of the lists, while getting elements from the other list by index. In your case, the lists are like `someMap?keys`, and with that it's like:

```
<#assign bKeys = bMap?keys>
<#list aMap?keys as aKey>
  Key from aMap: ${aKey}
  Key from bMap: ${bKeys[aKey?index]}
</#list>
```

Regarding what's wrong with your code. If you nest the two `#list`-s into each other, then you will list the whole inner list for each element of the outer list.